# Migrate data to SQL DW for multiple tables

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm currently using Azure Data Factory to move over data from an Azure SQL database to an Azure DW instance.

This works fine for one table, but I have a lot of tables I'd like to move over. Using Azure Data Facory, it looks like I need to create a set of Source/Sink datasets and pipelines for every table in the database.

Is there a way to move multiple tables across without have to set up each table in the manner described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy operation allows you to select multiple tables to move in a single pipeline. From the Azure SQL Data Warehouse portal you can follow this process to setup a multi-table pipeline:

1. Click on the **Load Data** button
2. Select **Azure Data Factory**
3. Create a new data factory or use an existing one - ensure that the **Load Data** select is chosen
4. Select the **Run once now** option
5. Choose your Azure SQL Database source and enter the credentials
6. On the *Select Tables* screen, select multiple tables
7. Continue the Pipeline, save and execute